# Let A,B and C be sets. Using set identities, show that:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let A,B and C be sets. Using set identities, show that:

(a) $A\cup( B-A ) = A\cup B$

(b) $(A-B)-C = (A-C)-(B-C)$

How should I solve this problems?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

$$A\cup(B\setminus A)=A\cup(B\cap A^{c})=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup A^{c})=A\cup B$$
using the distributive law. Show the other one similarly.

Answer (score 0):

(b) $(A-B)-C = (A-C)-(B-C)$

I will use other approach proving the above:

First I'll show that $(A\setminus B)\setminus C \subseteq (A\setminus C)\setminus(B\setminus C)$.

Let $x\in (A\setminus B)\setminus C$. Thus $x\in (A\setminus B) $ and $x\notin C$, or  $x\in A $ and $x\notin B$ and $x\notin C$. Therefore $x\in (A\setminus C) $ and $x\notin B\setminus C$, thus $x\in (A\setminus C)\setminus( B\setminus C)$. Hence, $(A\setminus B)\setminus C \subseteq (A\setminus C)\setminus(B\setminus C)$.

Now, I will show that  $(A\setminus B)\setminus C \supseteq (A\setminus C)\setminus(B\setminus C)$

Let $x\in (A\setminus C)\setminus(B\setminus C)$. Then $x\in (A\setminus C)$ and $x\notin (B\setminus C)$. Thus, $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$, and $x\notin B$. I other words, $x\in (A\setminus B)\setminus C$, Hence, $(A\setminus B)\setminus C \supseteq (A\setminus C)\setminus(B\setminus C)$.

From these two above inclusions, we deduce $(A\setminus B)\setminus C =(A\setminus C)\setminus(B\setminus C)$

Comment: Good answer, but OP asked for set identities.